# Repeat Pandas dataframe row labels

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is there a way to repeat row labels with Pandas dataframe? My Excel output created with xlsxwriter currently doesn't repeat groupings at higher levels.
I appreciate any help.

How my Excel sheet looks like now:

```
Country   State/Province    Population
US        Califonia         38,802,500
          Texas             26,956,958
          Florida           19,893,297
...
CAN       Alberta            3,645,257
          Manitoba           4,400,057
```

I would like the output to have repeating country level labels like below

```
Country      State/Province        Population
US           California            38,802,500
US           Texas                 26,956,958
US           Florida               19,893,297
...
CAN          Alberta                3,645,257
CAN          Manitoba               4,400,057
```

Comment: I know nothing about Pandas and won't be able to answer your question.  There is a way to correct this problem manually in Excel after the fact:  Select your table.  Click Find & Select/Go To Special.  Select Blanks and hit OK.  Type equals sign and up arrow and hit Enter.  Press Control-Enter.  Press Control-C.  Then click Paste/Paste Special.  Select Values and hit OK.  These steps select the blank cells and fill them with a formula that displays the values of the above cell.  Then the results of the formulas are copied back into the workbook.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! Also, I just noticed that if I use to_csv method of a DataFrame object, the row labels are repeated. I just wish that to_excel exhibited the same behavior since my reports contain many sheets.

Comment: I assume it's because you have a multi-index?  In which case, just do `reset_index()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can import the excel data and then forward fill the relevant column:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df.Country.ffill(inplace=True)
>>> df
  Country State/Province  Population
0      US      Califonia    38802500
1      US          Texas    26956958
2      US        Florida    19893297
3     CAN        Alberta     3645257
4     CAN       Manitoba     4400057
```

If needed, you could then set the index to Country and State/Province.

```
>>> df.set_index(['Country', 'State/Province']) 
                        Population
Country State/Province            
US      Califonia         38802500
        Texas             26956958
        Florida           19893297
CAN     Alberta            3645257
        Manitoba           4400057
```

The original DataFrame could then be retrieved via `df.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 0):

just use

df --> is your pivoted DataFrame.

Use the below and the problem will be solved
df = df.reset_index()

Comment: Hi Sufiyan and Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please format your code? You can read here on [how to format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and here on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), thanks!