# How to use pandas to expand a groupby table to have the rows repeated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have data that is grouped by as the following:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZumtD.png)

I would like to expand the dataframe to be ungrouped into a table that looks like the image below:

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqbEl.png)

What would be the best way to repeat these items to get a simpler table?

I have tried to use unstack but I would like the columns to stay the same as they currently are.

Comment: Please do not link to images of data or code. The idea is that someone can take the data/code you provide and replicate the issue, without having to re-type it all. Copying from an image does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to interpret the images.

If this is a dataframe that you've aggregated and that's what's in pandas (what it looks like), and you just want to display with repeated labels I think you're just looking for a `.reset_index()`?

If you export it by `to_excel`,`to_csv`,`to_markdown` or the like, the labels will be repeated.

If it's an excel table with just null values, you'd want to fill the na's using the method `ffill`:

`my_df["id"] = my_df["id"].fillna(method="ffill")`

[here is a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852373/repeat-pandas-dataframe-row-labels)

Below demonstrates what the code does in each of the scenarios:

**reset_index**

```
>>> df
         a
id colb   
a  AA    1
   BB    2
b  CC    3
   DD    4
c  EE    5
   FF    6
d  GG    7
>>> 
>>> df.reset_index()
  id colb  a
0  a   AA  1
1  a   BB  2
2  b   CC  3
3  b   DD  4
4  c   EE  5
5  c   FF  6
6  d   GG  7
```

**testing export**

```
>>> df
         a
id colb   
a  AA    1
   BB    2
b  CC    3
   DD    4
c  EE    5
   FF    6
d  GG    7
>>> df.to_csv("testing_if_labels_repeat.csv")
>>> pd.read_csv("testing_if_labels_repeat.csv")
  id colb  a
0  a   AA  1
1  a   BB  2
2  b   CC  3
3  b   DD  4
4  c   EE  5
5  c   FF  6
6  d   GG  7
```

**if the source is an table with null values**

```
>>> df = pd.read_excel("table_file.xlsx")
>>> df
    id colb  cola
0    a   AA     1
1  NaN   BB     2
2    b   CC     3
3  NaN   DD     4
4    c   EE     5
5  NaN   FF     6
6    d   GG     7

>>> df["id"] = df["id"].fillna(method="ffill")
>>> df
  id colb  cola
0  a   AA     1
1  a   BB     2
2  b   CC     3
3  b   DD     4
4  c   EE     5
5  c   FF     6
6  d   GG     7
>>>
```

Is that helpful? or are you trying for something different?